# PostgreSQL Can't Find `pg_cron` When Installed from `apk` On Alpine Container

Tags: postgresql, docker, alpine-linux, postgresql-extensions

## Issue Description

I'm attempting to install several postgreSQL extension on an alphine container. I'm using apk since there are packages that exist but when I'm attempting to load the extensions I'm hitting an error that says the extensions don't exist.

I am copying the `.control` and `.sql` files to the directory that I think is the correct extensions directory (`/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/`) but if I was doing this 100% correctly I wouldn't e asking this question. =P

I would love to know why I'm not able to load `pg_cron` in particular for this example and hopefully that'll let me use any other extensions loaded through apk going forward.

## Error Message

```bash
data-pipeline-db-1  | 2024-02-22 00:58:00.127 UTC [37] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections                                                                                                     
data-pipeline-db-1  |  done 
data-pipeline-db-1  | server started
data-pipeline-db-1  | CREATE DATABASE 
data-pipeline-db-1  |
data-pipeline-db-1  |  
data-pipeline-db-1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: sourcing /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/001-create-db.sh 
data-pipeline-db-1  | CREATE DATABASE 
data-pipeline-db-1  | CREATE ROLE
data-pipeline-db-1  | GRANT
data-pipeline-db-1  |
data-pipeline-db-1  | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: sourcing /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/002-setup.sh
data-pipeline-db-1  | waiting for server to shut down...2024-02-22 00:58:00.584 UTC [37] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
data-pipeline-db-1  | .2024-02-22 00:58:00.584 UTC [37] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
data-pipeline-db-1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
data-pipeline-db-1  | 
data-pipeline-db-1  | 2024-02-22 00:58:02.475 UTC [1] FATAL:  could not access file "pg_cron": No such file or directory
data-pipeline-db-1  | 2024-02-22 00:58:02.475 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

## Files Required To Reproduce Issue

### Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:16.2-alpine

# These are special environment variables that are used by the postgreSQL init
# script. They'll create a DB and user based on whatever values they're populated
# with.
ENV POSTGRES_DB ""
ENV POSTGRES_USER ""
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD ""
ENV POSTGRES_CONF ""
ENV PATH="/usr/pgsql-16/bin:${PATH}"

# Variables needed at runtime to configure postgres and run the initdb scripts
ARG PG_PARTMAN_VERSION
ARG PG_CRON_VERSION
ARG PG_GIS_VERSION
ARG USER="data-pipeline"

RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-pg_cron="${PG_CRON_VERSION}-r0" --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community \
    && apk add --no-cache postgresql-pg_partman="${PG_PARTMAN_VERSION}-r0" --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing \
    && apk add --no-cache postgis="${PG_GIS_VERSION}-r0" --repository=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community \
    && cp /usr/share/postgresql/extension/* /usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/
# Tried to copy the .so file but that didn't solve my issue.
#RUN cp -r /usr/lib/postgresql16/ usr/local/lib/postgresql/


# Question: Why do we need this entry point if we've already installed the extensions?
# Answer: PostgreSQL needs to be running in order to install extensions and
#         we can't start PostgreSQL until after we're done building the container
#         So we're chosing to add scripts to run on container start to circumvent
#         the chicken or egg problem.
# Copy in the load-extensions script
COPY db/initdb_scripts /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  data-pipeline-db:
    image: data-pipeline-db
    restart: always
    shm_size: 512mb
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/db/Dockerfile
      args:
          PG_CRON_VERSION: 1.6.2
          PG_PARTMAN_VERSION: 5.0.0
          PG_GIS_VERSION: 3.4.2
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./data/pgsql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=testing
      - POSTGRES_USER=data-pipeline
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test

  data-pipeline-testing:
    image: data-pipeline-testing
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/testing/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
```

The content of `db/initdb_scripts`:

```
$ tree db/initdb_scripts
db/initdb_scripts
├── 001-create-db.sh
├── 002-setup.sh
├── 003-load-extensions.sql
└── README.md
```

#### 001-create-db.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    CREATE DATABASE "$POSTGRES_USER";
    CREATE USER new_user_name WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '"$POSTGRES_PASSWORD"';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "$POSTGRES_USER" TO "$POSTGRES_USER";
EOSQL
```

#### 002-setup.sh

```
cat <<EOT >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
shared_preload_libraries='pg_cron'
cron.database_name='${POSTGRES_DB:-postgres}'
EOT

pg_ctl restart
```

#### 003-load-extensions.sql

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron;
SELECT * FROM pg_extension;

CREATE SCHEMA partman;
CREATE EXTENSION pg_partman SCHEMA partman;
select * FROM pg_extension;
```

## Other Things I've Tried

- I tried to change the `postgres.conf` location from `/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf` to `/etc` but this had no effect.
- I tried doing a `cp /usr/lib/postgresql16/pg_cron.so /usr/local/lib/pg_cron/` given that `$LIBDIR` is in `/usr/local/lib`
- - I tried doing a `cp /usr/lib/postgresql16/pg_cron.so /usr/local/lib/` instead of in `pg_cron`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal setup which will resolve your problem. I believe that the crux is copying the files across from `/usr/lib/` to `/usr/local/lib/` and from `/usr/share/` to `/usr/local/share/`.

For clarity I have stripped down the files to contain just what's required to get `pg_cron` loaded.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  data-pipeline-db:
    image: data-pipeline-db
    restart: always
    container_name: data-pipeline-db
    shm_size: 512mb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=testing
      - POSTGRES_USER=data-pipeline
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM postgres:16.2-alpine

ENV POSTGRES_DB ""
ENV POSTGRES_USER ""
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD ""

RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-pg_cron && \
    cp /usr/lib/postgresql16/pg_cron.so /usr/local/lib/postgresql/ && \
    cp /usr/share/postgresql16/extension/* /usr/local/share/postgresql/extension

COPY setup-pg-cron.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

`setup-pg-cron.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

cat <<EOT >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
shared_preload_libraries='pg_cron'
cron.database_name='postgres'
EOT
```

It made more sense to me to append the entry to `/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf` at build time rather than initialisation time.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is still giving me `ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "cron.database_name"` when running `CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron;` in the DB after running `docker-compose up` with the example posted above. It gets me to where I'm currently stuck at which is a running PostgreSQL instance but not a working set of extensions.

Comment: So I wasn't able to get this to work with the echos in the Dockerfile but I was able to get this to work with an init script for some reason. When I ran `SHOW config_file;` while connected to the DB it wasn't showing the echo'd changes on my machine. I'm on an OSX machine so I'm wondering if this is a bit of weirdness about the image being run on a VM. 

Regardless this effectively put me on the path to getting a working solution so I'm going to accept this answer.

Comment: Aha! I have made some edits.  If you have an existing volume with the database on it then you'll need to remove that volume. The startup scripts (which are being used to load `pg_cron` are only run when there is no existing database ("Warning: scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d are only run if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup.").